# Show ng-container content as a popup

Tags: html, css, angular

How can I make this content in the code below show up as a new popup on the page when triggered and not in a specific section? Is it related to a z-index?

Thanks

```
<ng-container *ngIf="confirmation">
      <div class="check-email">
        <div class="title-email" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">{{ 'check-email-title' | translate }}</div>
        <div class="sub-title" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">{{ 'verify-email' | translate }}</div>
        <div class="email-img" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <img src="assets/img/email-message.png" />
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          {{ 'do-not-see-email' | translate }}
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          {{ 'check-spam-folder' | translate }}
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <a class="click-resend-email">Click here &nbsp;</a>
          <div>to send the email again</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

## main

======================

**First**, you can give the "ng-container" a `position` property with a value of `absolute` or `fixed` (depending on your application), this will make "ng-container" appear on top of everything else **if it is the last element in your HTML file**, this is what I usually do if no rules were put within the team I was working on, however, if for some reason you can't put it at the end then you can use `z-index` property with the proper value (usually high number like 1000 if you want to cover everything else that you might've added `z-index` to). *[I'm not saying that adding the element to the last is a best practice but this is what I do especially for small projects]*.

**Second**, use properties `top`, `right`, `left`, and `bottom` to adjust the position of your element (you don't need to use all of them)

**Third**, you can assign the `display` property of "ng-container" the value of `none` at the start, and whenever you want the container to appear you can change the value of the `display` property to whatever you want using Js.

```
ng-container {
    display: block; // or any display setting you're using.
    position: fixed; 
    top: 1rem ;    //
    right: 1rem;   // adjust the position as you need. 
    left: 1rem;    //
    bottom: 1rem;  //
}
```

=====================

#### additional

---

**1** - you might want to wrap the whole thing in a container to make some kind of an effect to let the user know they need to focus on that element, like blurring or darkening everything else behind your popup, simply you need the wrapping container to have the full width and height of the screen using the values `100vw` and `100vh` for the `width` and `hight` properties respectively, `vw` and `vh` is to specify how much to take from the viewport in height or width.

**2** - you can change the `overflow` property of the body to the value `hidden` if you don't want scroll ability during this popup.

**3** - you can detect if the user clicks on the wrapper to cancel this popup (if the element doesn't take all the width of the container).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).